# How to find last letter on word in string with find method?

Tags: python, find, letter

Like the title says.
I'm not working on high project or something but that question just wonders me.

```
Meri = "Meri: We are class"
Meri_1 = Meri.find('Meri')
print(Meri_1)
```

I would like to find the first and last letter on the word "Meri", that means 
to print 0 and 3.

Comment: `print(Meri_1[0]) print(Meri_1[3])` ?

Comment: This will just print the letters that are on that offset, but i want to print the offset of these two letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know the length of the string that you are trying to find the last letter of, you can do:

```
search_string = "Meri"
print(Meri.find(search_string) + len(search_string) - 1)
```

All that this does is take the length of the string you are trying to find, add it to the index of the start of the string and then subtract 1 to get the last character of that string.
Using the example that you have, `Meri.find(search_string)` will return 0 and when you add `len(search_string)` gives you 4, but because strings index at 0, you need to subtract 1 to give the correct index.

Comment: Thanks, this do the job. I was expecting something with find but this give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
word = "Gaben"
index = word.index("b")
print(index)    #Output: 2
```

If you want reverse try

```
word = "Gabe will love Gabe"
last_index = word.rindex("Gabe")
print(last_index)    #Output: 15
```